# Is there a way to change the minimum touch contact diameter on the ipad?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios5

I know that the minimum contact diameter that will register as a touch on the ipad is 6 mm. I am wondering if there is a way to make the minimum touch contact smaller than 6 mm programmatically or otherwise?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not. You have absolutely no control over touch diameters.

Comment: @novicePrgrmr: I have no idea what it is. It's undocumented, and it's not something you're supposed to care about.